# (Java) Array of JTextFields with entered values, returns null

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jtextfield

ShortcutPicker class only uses JFileChooser to pick a file. But when i have loaded all paths into the textFields and try to call printData() it only prints out default, except the last index, there the value is printed.

Can't really seem to find the error.

Hope someone can help me solve this, thank you!

```
class ShortcutPickerPanel extends JPanel
{

    private int amountOfShortcuts;
    private JTextField[] textFields;

    private ShortcutPicker picker = new ShortcutPicker();

    public ShortcutPickerPanel( int amountOfShortcuts )
    {
        this.amountOfShortcuts = amountOfShortcuts;
        setLayout( new GridLayout( amountOfShortcuts, 3, 2, 2 ) );
        setup();
    }

    /**
     * Method initializes and add component's. 
     */
    public void setup()
    {
        this.textFields = new JTextField[ amountOfShortcuts ];
        BrowseButtonListener listener = new BrowseButtonListener();

        for( int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++ )
        {
            textFields[ i ] = new JTextField( "Default", 20 );
            BrowseButton button = new BrowseButton( "Browse", i );
            JLabel currentLabel = new JLabel( "Shortcut path:" );
            button.addActionListener( listener );
            add( currentLabel );
            add( textFields[ i ] );
            add( button);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if data in textfields are ok 
     */
    public boolean dataOk()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method to print data:
     * Lets say i have 2 fields initiated here, only the last field will have a value?? 
     */
    public void printData()
    {
        System.out.println( "Length: " + textFields.length  );

        for( int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( textFields[ i ].getText() );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener for BrowseButton 
     */
    private class BrowseButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
        {
            BrowseButton button = ( BrowseButton ) event.getSource();

            File selectedFile = picker.chooseFile();
            if( selectedFile != null )
            {
                textFields[ button.getTextFieldIndex() ].setText( 
                        selectedFile.getAbsolutePath() );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom BrowseButton for holding textFieldIndex 
     */
    private class BrowseButton extends JButton
    {
        private int textFieldIndex;

        public BrowseButton( String text, int textFieldIndex )
        {
            super( text );
            this.textFieldIndex = textFieldIndex;
        }

        public int getTextFieldIndex()
        {
            return textFieldIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How and where `amountOfShortcuts` gets its value?

Comment: amountOfShortcuts gets it value when initializing before adding to JFrame.